# Parameters double posting ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It seems that my hashtag is being sent through the form wrong, instead of just #content it is coming through as  `{"hashtag"=>"#content"},`

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"h4S3tOePv3+tUY3o10lc2uEHP92+s6oGhv727uEcR5A=", "hashtag"=>{"hashtag"=>"#content"}, "commit"=>"Submit!"}
```

**controller**

```
class HashtagsController < ApplicationController

    def home 
        @hashtag = Hashtag.new(params[:hashtag])    
        @random_hashtags = Hashtag.order("RANDOM()").limit(4)
    end

    def create
    hash_search = params[:hashtag]
    Twitter.search("yahoo", :lang => "en", :count => 100, :result_type => "recent").results.map do |tweet|
        Hashtag.create!(
            tweet_id: tweet.id,
            text: tweet.text,
            profile_image_url: tweet.profile_image_url,
            from_user: tweet.from_user,
            created_at: tweet.created_at,
            hashtag: hash_search
        )   
        end
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

**form**

```
<%= form_for(@hashtag) do |f| %>
                <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                <span class="add-on swag">#</span>

                <%= f.text_field :hashtag , class: "span3 inverse", id:"appendedPrependedInput" %>

                <%= f.submit "Swag!", class: "btn btn-inverse" %>
                <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a field called `hashtag` with a value `#content`, on a form for an object of class `Hashtag`, hence:

{hashtag(class): {hashtag(field): '#content'}}

Comment: Its causing `--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
` to be entered into the database instead of the actual content

Comment: Because you aren't coding your create action for the params you're getting, you're coding it for what you *want*, which I've already explained to you is not what you get.